# Join 3 tables two have primary key and third one have both foreign keys

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have three table A, B, C,

Table A is having primary_key a.id_attr and other column is a.id_attr_group.

Table B has one primary key b.id_prod_attr and other column is b.id_prod

Table C

And Third and last one is combination of both keys c.id_attr and c.id_prod_attr
in table c their could be multiple entries having 2-3 same rows from both table.

I want to get unique rows those fulfill the condition a.id_attr_group=2 and b.id_prod=1 and those both condition matches in Table C [combinations]
I have tried the Inner join, LEFT OUTER JOIN Subquery but no use not able to get the exact results.

Thanks in advance if someone could help me out?

Comment: if i were you, i would add a schema desscription for my tables, not phrasing them as a paragraph...

Comment: Use EXISTS() as a join condition between A and B.

Answer (score 1):

Wait so you have

A

id_attr                                 [PK] 
id_attr_group             [UNIQUE] (presumably)

B

id_prod_attr                    [PK] 
id_prod                                   [UNIQUE] (presumably)

C

#id_attr                                  [FK from A] 
#id_prod_attr                 [FK from B]

and then I am not really sure about what you're trying to do.

can't you just do

SELECT * 
FROM C INNER JOIN B ON B.id_prod_attr = C.id_prod_attr 
INNER JOIN A  ON A.id_attr = C.id_attr 
WHERE A.id_attr_group = 2 and B.id_prod = 1 
?

Answer (score 0):

```
select *

from HomeLoan  -- this table  has the foreign keys
inner join Home on Home.homeNumber = HomeLoan.homeNumber
inner join HomeOwner on HomeOwner.ownerNID = HomeLoan.ownerNID  --3 table join
```

Where the 3 tables you are joining are `HomeLoan`, `Home` and `HomeOwner`.